# Minion Pro Font for TeXMaker

Tags: minionpro

I tried to use the Minion Pro font style in my document but TeXMaker gives me an error message saying that no `MinionPro.sty` can be found. When using `\setmainfont{Minion Pro}` TexMaker does not know the package although I installed minion2newtx in the package manager.

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue and make this my main font for the document?

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{float}% If comment this, figure moves to Page 2
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=blue
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

%\date{\today}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{style = Matlab-editor}

\pretitle{%
  \begin{center}
  \LARGE
  \includegraphics[width=10cm,height=3cm]{logo}\\[\bigskipamount]
}
\posttitle{\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\title{Testdocument}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a compilable code snippet to help us help you.

Comment: Added the code snippet that compiles. Now when I want to add the font, it gives me an error. If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to `minion2newtx`? You need to obtain the actual font (not only the support package) and install it, following the instructions in sections 1.1 to 1.3

Comment: Sorry for the question but just download it from there: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/ ? I am curious that I cannot download this directly from the Package Manager. Do I have to put ALL the files into a specific folder?

Comment: Everything is explained in the `readme` file. You'll also have to use the `LCDF type tools` to make the `.vf` and `.pfb` files.

Comment: Bottom line: The Minion Pro fonts are not free fonts. They are a commercial product of Adobe. Therefore, TeX cannot distribute them. All TeX can do is provide support files, IF you are otherwise licensed to have and use the Minion Pro fonts.  Perhaps you have that, perhaps not; it depends on what else is on your system, and how you use the fonts.

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` too early.

Comment: Also thanks @Bernard. There is really no "proper" help in the internet for this font. Probably also because of this Adobe issue. I will let you guys know how it works then.

Comment: You can use these fonts (which come with Acrobat Reader) with pdflatex (I use them for some of my documents). As far as I remember, it took a certain time to obtain all necessary  files, but the instructions in the readme file was all I needed (also understanding where to put all these files. If you only want to use them for text, using `fontspec` and `xelatex` is much simpler, as you can use the system fonts.

Comment: Finally solved it @Bernard! As mentioned in my answer I used another source for the solution. It is way better explained than in the link I posted in the comment. Thanks and enjoy your weekend!

Comment: @MatlabNewb: I've just taken a look at the document you mention, which does more or less what is described in the `readme` file, with explanations on where to put the produced files and how to  refresh the type1 fonts databases (`psfonts.map` and the like). Just a couple of observation: the local TeXMF folder should not be installed in a user's directory if you want any user to have access to the fonts, but, say in a place like `C:\TeXMF-local`. And I'm not sure the LCDF type tools should be installed in the MiKTeX root directory, but in the local TeXMF directory (it might deleted on update).

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for your hints. For me the document I posted is more convenient imo also due to the fact that this is more "Windows based". But you are right. I ran into some trouble when updating via MikTeX. Finally made it work and there seem to be no more issues. Still have the impression that the compilation time is way higher now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by following the instructions on this page here: [MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub](https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub)

I used the following PDF as a instructions: [MikTeX Installation Guide](https://github.com/henrikgit/MPro-Installation-Guide-GitHub/blob/master/mpro-installation-guide-miktex.pdf)

General steps:

1) Download all the software you most likely do not have on your PC.

2) Download all the LATEX-font-files (let’s call them “metrics”) for Minion Pro and Myriad Pro you most likely do not have on your PC.

3) Install LCDF typetools for MikTeX.

4) Convert the .otf-files.

5) Put the files into the right place.

6) Get ready

P.S.: Make sure you install/copy-paste everything into the right folder. Otherwise you will have a bad time. You have to make sure that you choose the right folders or TeXMaker will throw error messages. You can fix that by updating the packages given in the error message and "Refresh FNDB" in the MikTeX Settings.